# Extract data from XML Clob using SQL from Oracle Database

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, parsing, clob

I want to extract the value of Decision using sql from table TRAPTABCLOB having column testclob with XML stored as clob.

Sample XML as below.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DCResponse>
    <Status>Success</Status>
    <Authentication>
        <Status>Success</Status>
    </Authentication>
    <ResponseInfo>
        <ApplicationId>5701200</ApplicationId>
        <SolutionSetInstanceId>
                        63a5c214-b5b5-4c45-9f1e-b839a0409c24
                    </SolutionSetInstanceId>
        <CurrentQueue />
    </ResponseInfo>
    <ContextData>
        <!--Decision Details Start-->
        <Field key="SoftDecision">A</Field>
        <Field key="**Decision**">1</Field>
        <Field key="NodeNo">402</Field>
        <Field key="NodeDescription" />
        <!--Decision Details End-->
        <!--Error Details Start-->
        <Field key="ErrorResponse">
            <Response>
                <Status>[STATUS]</Status>
                <ErrorCode>[ERRORCODE]</ErrorCode>
                <ErrorDescription>[ERRORDESCRIPTION]</ErrorDescription>
                <Segment>[SEGMENT]</Segment>
            </Response>
        </Field>
        <Field key="ErrorCode">0</Field>
        <Field key="ErrorDescription" />
    </ContextData>
</DCResponse>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(testclob), '/DCResponse/ContextData/Field[@key="Decision"]') 
FROM traptabclob;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cc513/4) is a sqlfiddle demo

Comment: Hi.. I am having similar issue.Can you help me out.The SQL Fiddle doesnt work.

Comment: Great it works now.. How can I extract the entire content and right it to a file?

Comment: @SOaddict, the entire content is in `testclob` you can extract whatever you want with the right XPATH expression (2nd param of extract function). As to how to write it to a file - this is a whole different post... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562/oracle-write-to-file) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253440/how-to-output-oracle-sql-result-into-a-file-in-windows)

Comment: How can we read the value of "key" attribute of the first <Field>?

Comment: i try this and it's not work , also SQL Fiddle not worked too .

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(column_name, '/DCResponse/ContextData/Decision') FROM traptabclob;
```

I have assumed the ** were just for highlighting?

Comment: Not working - getting Ora-00932 error. Solution by A.B.Cade worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problem with XMLTYPE phrase, then try this:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT textClob), '/DCResponse/ContextData/Field[@key="Decision"]') FROM traptabclob;
```

This is usually because the column textClob has an invalid format of XML.
XMLParse parses and generates an XML instance from the evaluated result of value_expr. See [XMLPARSE, Oracle Database Online Documentation 11g, Release 2 (11.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions246.htm)