# How to output oracle sql result into a file in windows?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I tried

```
select * from users 
save D:\test.sql create;
```

But SQL plus gives me "no proper ended"
How to specify path in oracle sql in windows?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the spool:

```
spool myoutputfile.txt
select * from users;
spool off;
```

Note that this will create myoutputfile.txt in the directory from which you ran SQL*Plus.

If you need to run this from a SQL file (e.g., "tmp.sql") when SQLPlus starts up and output to a file named "output.txt":

tmp.sql:

```
select * from users;
```

Command:

```
sqlplus -s username/password@sid @tmp.sql > output.txt
```

Mind you, I don't have an Oracle instance in front of me right now, so you might need to do some of your own work to debug what I've written from memory.

Comment: thank you but can I ask where is the spool file myoutputfile.txt locate? Also what about user don't have permission to run spool?

Comment: Also how can we specify a path/folder of the output file, especially in Windows?

Comment: I've never had luck specifying where the spool is written to except to run `sqlplus.exe` from the directory where the spool output will go.

Comment: Could you give an example of the sqlplus.exe version? does it like sqlplus -s username/password@database.domain.com < tmp.sql > path\output.txt?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  From SQL*plus, type exactly what I wrote in my solution.  You will get output in a file named `myoutputfile.txt`.  If you don't see it where you expected it, perform a search for it.  How are you executing SQLPlus?  From what directory?

Comment: You're changing the question now.  I guess I'll update my answer.

Comment: Note that if you do not specify a file extension  on the spool file name (like .txt in the example), the extension .lst will be automatically appended.

Answer (score 21):

Very similar to Marc, only difference I would make would be to spool to a parameter like so:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
SET LINES 32000
SET TERMOUT OFF ECHO OFF NEWP 0 SPA 0 PAGES 0 FEED OFF HEAD OFF TRIMS ON TAB OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

spool &1

-- Code

spool off
exit
```

And then to call the SQLPLUS as

```
sqlplus -s username/password@sid @tmp.sql /tmp/output.txt
```

Comment: Yep.  I was gonna add the `set pages 0`, `set trimspool on`, etc.  But then the question changed and I had to chase down something else!  Good suggestions though.

Comment: Thanks John, your version returns clean SQL output I was looked for

Answer (score 4):

```
spool "D:\test\test.txt"

select  
  a.ename  
from  
  employee a  
inner join department b  
on  
(  
  a.dept_id = b.dept_id  
)  
;  
spool off
```

This query will spool the sql result in D:\test\test.txt

Answer (score 2):

just to make the Answer 2 much easier, you can also define the folder where you can put your saved file

```
    spool /home/admin/myoutputfile.txt
    select * from table_name;
    spool off;
```

after that only with nano or vi myoutputfile.txt, you will see all the sql track.

hope is that help :)

Answer (score 2):

Having the same chore on windows 10, and windows server 2012.
I found the following solution:

```
echo quit |sqlplus schemaName/schemaPassword@sid @plsqlScript.sql > outputFile.log
```

#### Explanation

`echo quit |` send the quit command to exit `sqlplus` after the script completes

`sqlplus schemaName/schemaPassword@sid @plsqlScript.sql` execute plssql script `plsqlScript.sql` in schema `schemaName` with password `schemaPassword` connecting to SID `sid`

`> outputFile.log` redirect sqlplus output to  log file `outputFile.log`

Comment: It's better to spool inside the `.sql` file I think.  Redirecting standard output to file may result in unwanted SQL feedback output in your file.  Also, you could just `quit` (or `exit`) inside the `.sql` file.