# Extract data from XML Clob using SQL from Oracle Database 11g

Tags: oracle11g, extract

I am unable to extract the particular XML Tag. Could you please someone assist me? When i execute this query:

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.substr(A.ACK) FROM ESM_OWNER.ACKNOWLEDGMENT A WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL;
```

it's giving the output as row which consist of:

```
<!DOCTYPE ichicsrack SYSTEM "http://eudravigilance.ema.europa.eu/dtd/ichicsrack11xml.dtd"><ichicsrack lang="en">
  <ichicsrmessageheader>
   <messagetype>ICHICSRACK</messagetype>
   <messagedate>20140602022242</messagedate>
  </ichicsrmessageheader>
    <acknowledgment>
     <messageacknowledgment>
      <icsrmessagenumb>LCR-UCB SA20140529181</icsrmessagenumb>
      <transmissionacknowledgmentcode>01</transmissionacknowledgmentcode>
     </messageacknowledgment>
       <reportacknowledgment>
        <safetyreportversion>1</safetyreportversion>
        <errormessagecomment>Imported Case #: 2014000015, Initial case created ; PCYC-1103-CA ; OCCURCOUNTRY is NULL in SAFETYREPORT. Module : CREATE_CASE_MASTER ; DTD Element TESTRESULT and DTD Element TESTUNIT both shall contain the value in order to update the record. ; DTD E</errormessagecomment>
       </reportacknowledgment>
    </acknowledgment>
</ichicsrack>
```

I would like to retrieve the errormessagecomment tag through SQL buti was unable to do it.

I took the help from the below mentioned link:
[Extract data from XML Clob using SQL from Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600480/extract-data-from-xml-clob-using-sql-from-oracle-database)
But still i am unable to retrieve the value,can someone assist me.I have tried all the possibility whole day but still i was unable to retrieve tag.

Comment: Do you get an error message? What is the result of the things you have tried? The article you link to uses older syntax, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't work.