# Using SQL to extract values from xml CLOB

Tags: xml, plsql, clob

I'm currently trying to figure out on how to extract some values using plsql from a xml CLOB value that is stored in my database.

My CLOB value looks like the following:

```
<map>
  <entry>
    <string>HeaderOne</string>
    <string>
        <linked-hash-map>
            <entry>
                <string>ID</string>
                <string>81</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>Name</string>
                <string>John</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>SecondName</string>
                <string>Smith</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>Age</string>
                <string>15</string>
            </entry>
        </linked-hash-map>
    </string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>HeaderTwo</string>
    <string>
        <linked-hash-map>
            <entry>
                <string>ID</string>
                <string>81</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>ZIP</string>
                <string>99999</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>Gender</string>
                <string>M</string>
            </entry>
        </linked-hash-map>
    </string>
  </entry>
</map>
```

I tried using the EXTRAC(xmltype(myclob) method as described here:
[Extract data from XML Clob using SQL from Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600480/extract-data-from-xml-clob-using-sql-from-oracle-database)

However this won't work in my case because the `<string>` tag doesn't include an identifier suchs as 'name' or 'key', but instead lists another `<string>` entry above the actual value. I.e. `<string>ID</string>` is the parameter as one would normally use `<string name='ID'>81</string>` where '81' in this case is the actual value I want to be extracted.

The parameters can be listed in any order in the xml, however I know the name from the parameter I wish to extract. So my question is, is there a way to extract for example the value from the `<string>Name</string>` entry (in this case 'John', however this can be any value)

Comment: So the order of `<string>` elements inside an `<entry>` would decide whether it is the attribute name or value?

Comment: Yes you assume correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for ways to `PIVOT` the output if you like, but here's a start to how you would read such an XML -

For simplicity, assuming that the XML is inside a variable named my_xml of the type XMLTYPE.

```
SELECT header_string, attribute_name, attribute_value
  FROM (WITH xm AS (SELECT my_xml AS x FROM DUAL)
        SELECT header_string, linked_hash_map
          FROM xm,
               XMLTABLE (
                  '//map/entry'
                  PASSING xm.x
                  COLUMNS header_string VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'string[1]',
                          linked_hash_map XMLTYPE PATH 'string[2]/linked-hash-map'))
       l,
       XMLTABLE (
          '//linked-hash-map/entry'
          PASSING l.linked_hash_map
          COLUMNS attribute_name VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'string[1]',
                  attribute_value VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'string[2]');
```

I should mention that if possible, look for ways to improve the XML schema. From the question, it seems you already know that a better way is to use a key value pair where the key name isn't the actual data but the property of the element (if not the element name itself).

Also, don't use `EXTRACT` or `EXTRACTVALUE`, those functions have been deprecated by Oracle. Use `XMLTABLE` or `XMLQUERY` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check it out later and report back on the results!